# Google API : gauge animation

Tags: javascript, api, gauge

I am trying to make  google gauge pointer move, but it is not moving, I have set animation configuration as it suppose to be set in var options , such as duration : 1000 and easing: 'inAndOut' , I am n00b in Google API so for give my ignorance attempt.

can anyone help me.
here is the [tutorial link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge) that I am using it. the code is working but partially, the gauge pointer should move slowly to it's max, however, in my case it wont work. 
here is the code.

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Match',80],
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 440, height: 140,
      greenFrom: 70, greenTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:50, yellowTo: 70,
      redFrom:0, redTo: 50,
      minorTicks: 5,
      animation:{
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'inAndOut',
        },
      majorTicks : ['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div<%=id%>'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    clearChart();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue... I played with it a couple weeks ago and it worked fine but now its not animating at all.

Comment: Please check you code, as it stands it produces errors. I have got the gauges to draw by adding a body with a div with id `chart_div` and changing the `getElementId` parameter in the initialization of `chart`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I figured this one out myself, there's a nice answer in a google forums [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/YE-_ua-sYdc)

The trick is to start the gauge off with a 0 (or whatever your minimum) value is and then update the value later (using setInterval() or any other method)

There's definitely better ways of updating the value instead of just writing a new array but you get the idea.

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Match',0],
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 440, height: 140,
      greenFrom: 70, greenTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:50, yellowTo: 70,
      redFrom:0, redTo: 50,
      minorTicks: 5,
      animation:{
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'inAndOut',
        },
      majorTicks : ['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div<%=id%>'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    clearChart();

    // This is new.
    setTimeout(function(){
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Match',80],
      ]);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 200);
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone now, but I found using the setValue method moved me from static to animated needles. Below is a code snippet (I've got a number of gauge widgets, hence the array).

```
// set up the value here that we are moving from - this allows the gauge needle to animate when we set the actual value later
if (!widgetArray[i].googleArrayToDataTable) { // check if we've initialised

    widgetArray[i].googleArrayToDataTable = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      [widgetArray[i].label, 0]
    ]);
}
else {

    widgetArray[i].googleArrayToDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      [widgetArray[i].label, (widgetArray[i].googleOldNeedleValue * widgetArray[i].dialMax / widgetArray[i].googleOldDialMax)]
    ]);
}
// remember these values - I need to do this for my application to ensure the needle looks ok when switching values
widgetArray[i].googleOldNeedleValue = widgetArray[i].needleVal;
widgetArray[i].googleOldDialMax = widgetArray[i].dialMax;

majorTickIncrement = widgetArray[i].dialMax / 5;

var options;

if (widgetArray[i].range2End > 0)
    options = {
        height: 240,
        animation: { duration: 1000, easing: 'inAndOut' },
        //redFrom: 0, redTo: KRAvalues.targetVal,
        redFrom: 0, redTo: widgetArray[i].range1End,
        yellowFrom: widgetArray[i].range1End, yellowTo: widgetArray[i].range2End,
        greenFrom: widgetArray[i].range2End, greenTo: widgetArray[i].range3End,
        minorTicks: 5, max: widgetArray[i].dialMax,
        majorTicks: ['0', majorTickIncrement, majorTickIncrement * 2, majorTickIncrement * 3, majorTickIncrement * 4, widgetArray[i].dialMax]
    };
else
    options = {
        height: 240,
        animation: { duration: 1000, easing: 'inAndOut' },
        minorTicks: 5, max: widgetArray[i].dialMax,
        majorTicks: ['0', majorTickIncrement, majorTickIncrement * 2, majorTickIncrement * 3, majorTickIncrement * 4, widgetArray[i].dialMax]
    };

if (!widgetArray[i].googleChart) { // initialise gauge if required
    widgetArray[i].googleChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById(widgetArray[i].name + 'chart_div'));
}

// this animates the needle
// draw old value
widgetArray[i].googleChart.draw(widgetArray[i].googleArrayToDataTable, options);
// set new value
widgetArray[i].googleArrayToDataTable.setValue(0, 1, widgetArray[i].needleVal);
// draw new value
widgetArray[i].googleChart.draw(widgetArray[i].googleArrayToDataTable, options);
```