# Google Gauge Animation API not Working from Google Ajax Playground

Tags: google-visualization

the code below was copied from https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i tried using it first as a demo before moving it to my main project. But it seems it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! It happened to me after i dived into Google Chart to learn the Visualization API.. but this post solved my problem by +Alex [google-api-gauge-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349284/google-api-gauge-animation?answertab=oldest#tab-top)